# Why static member definitions can't have the keyword 'static'?

Tags: c++, static, datamember

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Player
{
private:
    int id;
    static int next_id;
public:
    int getID() { return id; }
    Player() { id = next_id++; }
};
static int Player::next_id = 1;

int main()
{
Player p1;
Player p2;
Player p3;
cout << p1.getID() << " ";
cout << p2.getID() << " ";
cout << p3.getID();
return 0;
}
```

output:

> prog.cpp:13:20: error: 'static' may not be used when defining (as opposed to declaring) a static data member

Please explain why we cannot have static in definition.

Comment: Please copy your code directly here in the future.

Comment: `static` at global scope means static linkage (not added to the export symbol table for other files to link to). so when you define a static member, we don't use the `static` keyword. it's a quirk of the language.

Comment: I guess it would be redundant since only static class fields can have out of class definitions.

Comment: @CruzJean please explain in detail.